# rpmbuild faild with: Installed (but unpackaged) file(s) found

Tags: python, build, centos, rpm

Hi I'm trying to build a rpm using python but it fails with this error.

```
RPM build errors:
Installed (but unpackaged) file(s) found:
( a list of files )
error: command 'rpmbuild' failed with exit status 1
```

this is the .spec file generated by python:

```
%define name prova
%define version 1.0.0
%define unmangled_version 1.0.0
%define unmangled_version 1.0.0
%define release 1

Name: %{name}
Version: %{version}
Release: %{release}
Source0: %{name}-%{unmangled_version}.tar.gz
License: LGPL-3
Group: Development/Libraries
BuildRoot: %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-buildroot
Prefix: %{_prefix}
BuildArch: noarch
Requires:  [...]

%prep
%setup -n %{name}-%{unmangled_version} -n %{name}-%{unmangled_version}

%build
python setup.py build

%install
#!/bin/sh
set -e
python setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed --prefix=/usr --root=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT --record=INSTALLED_FILES


%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%post
[...]

%files -f INSTALLED_FILES
%defattr(-,root,root)
```

and the command I use to build everything is this.

```
python setup.py bdist_rpm
```

As I have understand the install script should write a list of installed files in INSTALLED_FILES and then we pass the list of installed files to %files -f INSTALLED_FILES. But the --record options accept a file name where the setup script write the list of installed files and this is working. The problem is that the list is not read by the command %file -f.

Is that command deprecated? I have the version 4.11 of rpmbuild.

Comment: Have you looked in `INSTALLED_FILES` to ensure it is not blank?

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `--record` as that will not record directories.
See https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Python#Byte_compiling

Omit that option and simply use:

```
%files
%{python_sitelib}/
```